# Cross compilation error for beagle board. What is the bash error?

Tags: c, linux, bash, gcc

I am trying to make my .c file executable on beagle board. So when I extracted my arm-2010q1-202-arm-none-linux-gnueabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu.tar.bz2 file. I extracted it properly. and after extraction it is showing all files.

But when I am using "arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc", it shows below error. Can anybody please let me know about what kind of error is this?

```
shilpi@shilpi:~/Desktop$ file no
no: ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=98867ffb31348c9eecde7365ff33ee8a30a9eb6e, not stripped
shilpi@shilpi:~/Desktop$ arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -o hi1 no-17.c
bash: /home/shilpi/arm-2010q1/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: No such file or directory
shilpi@shilpi:~/Desktop$
```

Comment: What does `ls /home/shilpi/arm-2010q1/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc` say? What about `file /home/shilpi/arm-2010q1/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc`?

Comment: check whether you have exported the path or try compilation using absolute path

Comment: Does something simple like `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc --version` work?

Comment: @EtanReisner:ls shows the arm-none-gnueabi-gcc file but when I give path in .bashrc and then execute it. It shows "bash: /home/shilpi/arm-2010q1/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: No such file or directory"

Comment: @SantoshA: I have imported proper path.but its showing details of x_86 file details but not about arm executable file.

Comment: What did `file` say about that file? That sounds like a broken symlink possibly. What does `ls -l` say about it?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this problem when running a program intended for a different architecture, although the architecture itself isn't exactly the problem.

Example:

I have this old binary from 1997 for CB Zone hanging around (don't ask why..):

```
$ ls -Flas cbzone.exec 
60 -rwxr-xr-x 1 erlkonig dialout 59236 Sep 15  1997 cbzone.exec*
```

When I run it - even though it's obviously there:

```
$ ./cbzone.exec 
bash: ./cbzone.exec: No such file or directory
```

Tracing it isn't illuminating:

```
$ strace -f  ./cbzone.exec 
execve("./cbzone.exec", ["./cbzone.exec"], [/* 107 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "strace: exec: No such file or di"..., 40strace: exec: No such file or directory
) = 40
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

However, I'm on a x86_64 host and this program is for 32 bit, so something's probably missing:

```
$ file ./cbzone.exec 
./cbzone.exec: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped
```

ldd *does* report valid library support for most - not all - of the libs it needs.  A more useful hint is buried in this output:

```
$ readelf -a ./cbzone.exec
...
Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  PHDR           0x000034 0x08048034 0x08048034 0x000a0 0x000a0 R E 0x4
  INTERP         0x0000d4 0x080480d4 0x080480d4 0x00013 0x00013 R   0x1
     [Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld-linux.so.1]
  LOAD           0x000000 0x08048000 0x08048000 0x0c150 0x0c150 R E 0x1000
  LOAD           0x00c150 0x08055150 0x08055150 0x0209c 0x02d3c RW  0x1000
  DYNAMIC        0x00e12c 0x0805712c 0x0805712c 0x000c0 0x000c0 RW  0x4
....
```

Hmm, "interpreter"?

```
$ ls -Flas /lib/ld-linux.so.1
ls: cannot access /lib/ld-linux.so.1: No such file or directory
```

Ah. So the reason I'm not getting library-not-found errors is that is not even getting that far.  The first thing it needs... is missing.

See if these help diagnose the arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc issue.  :-)